# NSMutableArray. What is the fastest way to convert it to a plain ole C-array

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, nsmutablearray

I like the convenience of NSMutableArray but sometimes you just need to drop down to good ole C-arrays. Like when you are feeding interleaved vertex arrays to OpenGL.

What is the fastest way of copying the contents of an NSMutableArray to a C-array?

Yah, I realize this bit shuffling introduces inefficiency but I'd like to see if I can sneak by with this approach without taking a hit in frame rate.

Cheers,
Doug

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[from cocoabuilder mailing list](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/message/cocoa/2007/10/2/190184)

```
id *buffer = malloc(numberOf_ItemsIWant_ToFetch * sizeof(id));
[myArray getObjects:buffer range:rangeOfItems]
```

Answer (score 6):

See [`-[NSArray getObjects:]`](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/getObjects:). Just give it a buffer of the appropriate size and NSArray will fill the buffer with its contents. NSMutableArray is a subclass of NSArray, so it responds to all the same methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *arrayOfThings;
Element elements[arrayOfThings.count+1];

for (int i=0;i<arrayOfThings.count;i++)
{
    elements[i] = [arrayOfThings objectAtIndex:i];
}
```

Or something similar.  I don't see any easy way to do this in the Apple docs.

Answer (score 1):

```
int i=0;
foreach(YourClass *obj in array)
{
   carray[i++] = [obj yourMethodToConvertToCType];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers gang. Super quick. Super helpful.